# Using .iat with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, valueerror

I have two cells - one contains np.nan and the other contains 'example'.
I am trying to replace the null cell with a copy of the string, but I keep getting a value error that says

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'example'.

I don't understand why this needs/wants to convert to a float, how do I just replace the np.nan cell with a copy of the string in the other cell?
Thank you!

*Edit:* it seems that my problem is that I am trying to copy something from a dataframe col with dtype object (the string) and put it into a dataframe col with dtype float64 so that would make my error. I have tried both methods to convert those cols to type object but am not having success. Novice with pandas so I appreciate the patience.

*Edit2:* The issue was stemming from np.nan not being able to be cast to another type. Fixed, thanks!

```
        EHR_df.astype({"Scope2_Model": 'object',
                       "Scope2_Serial_Number": 'object',
                       "Scope2_Type": 'object'})
        EHR_df.astype('object', copy=False)
```

```
tester1 = EHR_df.iat[hybridInd[i+1], 24] # np.nan cell
tester2 = EHR_df.iat[hybridInd[i+1], 21] # cell containing 'example'
EHR_df.iat[hybridInd[i+1], 24] = tester2 # confused why this does not work
```

Comment: what are the dtypes of your dataframe? if you are trying to assign a string to a numeric column that will not work

Comment: @ifly6 I bet thats it, thank you! all of my columns are dtype object except for 24, 25, and 26 are float64. Will fix that, pretty new to pandas so I appreciate it!

Comment: print `df.head()` and add it to the question.